# What is the true method for JFrame, to minimize it in Linux

Tags: java, linux, swing, jframe

I made a JFrame using normal steps and *setSize*, *setVisible* and *setResizable* to false.

It's working fine under windows OS, but when I tried it in Fedora Linux, I found that the minimize button is not in the window bar, only the close button is in the window bar, so is JFrame used in different ways in Linux for minimizing?

Thank you.

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu/OpenJDK; please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/), and maybe someone using Fedora will test.

Comment: What shell are you using in Fedora? There is no minimize button in GNOME 3.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple cross-platform method in JFrame to operate the frame:

```
frame.setState ( JFrame.ICONIFIED );
frame.setState ( JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
frame.setState ( JFrame.NORMAL );
```

First one minimizes frame to OS bar, second one maximizes the frame and third one returns it to normal state. All of the operations done in a native-way.